# jQuery UI Slider to change percentage when select or input is changed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-slider

I am having problems updating the ui jquery slider when a select is changed or input is changed - anyone have any ideas on the source to resolve this?

```
$('.application-progress').slider({
    range: "min",
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    animate: true,
    slide: function(event, ui){
        $("#progress").html(ui.value+"%");
    }
});
$("#progress").html($(".application-progress").slider("value")+"%");

$('input').focusout(function(){
    var percentage = 0;
    $('input').each(function(){
        if($(this).val() != "")
            percentage += 10;
    });
    $("#progress").slider({value: percentage});
    $("#progress").html($(".application-progress").slider("value")+"%");
});​
```

I have added to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ykx5f/1/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that you are trying to achieve?

```
$("input, select").change(function() {
    var percentage = 0;
    $('input, select').each(function() {
        if ($.trim(this.value) != "") percentage += 10;
    });
    $(".application-progress").slider("value", percentage);

    $("#progress").html(percentage + "%");
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Ykx5f/9/

---

And here is the updated version, which automatically calculates the percentage based on the number of input fields:

```
$("input, select").change(function() {
    var fields = $("input, select");
    var percentage = 100 * fields.filter(function() {
        return $.trim(this.value) != "";
    }).length / fields.length;

    $(".application-progress").slider("value", percentage);
    $("#progress").html(percentage + "%");
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Ykx5f/11/

Comment: Works great with the inputs but select does not?

Comment: It will work if you change the value of "Select Title" option: `<option value="">Select Title</option>`. See the updated fiddle.

Comment: My bad it does seem to work, but the 1st is a dropdown and when changed just to 50% 1st?

Comment: I changed the value on selects and works a treat! thanks very much!

Comment: @JamesBrandon You are welcome! BTW, check the better version in the updated answer.

Comment: I use that new version and with all fields and selects used i get 91.66666666666667%

Comment: @JamesBrandon You can use `Math.round(percentage)`.

Comment: I used the math round and works perfect however even though completing the 10 fields i only get 92%

Comment: Its ok, i resolved it - was because i had some other inputs in the footer so i made it more specific to that form and works great! thanks all

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ykx5f/4/). Attach to the change event rather than the focusout/blur.